# How to find a country code in multiple languages

Tags: java, hashmap, locale

My problem is that I got a list of countries in different languages. All in text file. E.g:

```
pl_PL   Japonia
en_GB   Spain
en_EN   Portugal
```

I am seeking a way to find the code of the country, knowing name in different languages, so i could print it in another languages. E.g:

```
pl_PL   Japonia    -- translate to english -->     en_EN  Japan
en_EN   Portugal   -- translate to polish  -->     pl_PL  Portugalia
```

I was thinking to make a hashmap for each language where I would put all available countries and codes, but I don't have idea how to make it. I made already one map like this, but I don't know how to make it for multiple languages.

```
    Locale[] allLocs = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    Map map = new HashMap();
    String country = null;

    for (int j=0; j<allLocs.length; j++) {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale(langArray[0]));
        String countryCode = allLocs[j].getCountry();

        if (countryCode.equals("")) continue;
        kraj =  allLocs[j].getDisplayCountry();
        map.put(country , allLocs[j]);
    }
```

Comment: The Question is not clear. What is driving the translation of what to what? The [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class offers a few `getDisplay…` methods for translating the name of a language, country/region, and script. How does that not suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Locale construction went wrong in your attempts. You need to retrieve the following from the input file:

```
    final Locale locale1 = new Locale("pl", "PL");
    final String country1 = "Japonia";
```

Then given the target locale:

```
    final Locale locale2 = new Locale("en", "US");
```

One can find the country as you did. In java 8:

```
    final Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    Optional<String> country2 = Stream.of(locales)
            .filter((loc) -> country1.equals(loc.getDisplayCountry(locale1)))
            .map((cloc) -> cloc.getDisplayCountry(locale2))
            .filter((s) -> !s.isEmpty())
            .findAny();
    System.out.println(country2.orElse("not found"));
```

1. This searches every loc with the display country in the first language.
2. Then that cloc of the corresponding country is used for the display country in the second language.
3. Non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is called [exonym or xenonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exonym_and_endonym) and there is no out of the box class for that in java,

I would suggest to create a Pair class and then a `map<string, pair>` so you can match all the combinations in the application

## example:

```
public class I18N {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> languages;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new I18N();
    }
    public I18N() {
    this.languages = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> l = new HashMap<String, String>();
    l.put("Spanish", "Japon");
    l.put("Polnish", "Japonia");
    languages.put("Japan", l);
    //
    System.out.println(languages.get("Japan").get("Polnish"));
    }
}
```

so this snippet will look for the country japan and then for that name in the language polnish...

the bad part is that you will need to populate your own Exonym Catalog